# Is there 'Space Etiquette' for orientation?

Tags: microgravity, psychology

Is there a set of rules or guidelines for how one ought to behave whilst in space?

Apart from all of the necessary rules in place for safety reasons, do astronauts and cosmonauts live by a unique etiquette, necessary only when in space?

One thing that stands out to me is conversing to others in zero-G. I'd find it especially annoying if the person I was talking was upside-down and refused to 'stand in line'(?).

Have there been any studies on how others react when a person defies both social norms and natural laws (*gravity*) at the same time?  Are there any documented suggestions or protocols for how to orient yourself to others?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etiquette.

Comment: Etiquette is typically a cultural thing. Rules are written after the fact based on what is accepted culturally. Manned space travel is not yet a large enough phenomenon for a definitive culture to have yet formed, so any answers will be opinion-based.

Comment: While I agree that in it's present form this question is out of scope, if it could be written much less broad it could be a good question.

Comment: I think you all might be taking the word "etiquette" a bit hyperliterally. I don't think the question is terribly outside our scope, but I do agree it might be opinion-based. Would be better off asking if, say, NASA has any written, spoken, or unspoken rules as to how one should behave in space (barring standard procedures and contingency plans).

Comment: @ZachSmith If you agree that the question *as-written* is opinion-based, then there is a problem. The on-hold system exists specifically to encourage users to craft a better question as you have recommended.

Comment: Surely people have been living on the I.S.S. long enough to have developed some form of etiquette? I wouldn't go as far as to say that an astronaut would be highly offended for anything I've mentioned above were to occur, just having a preferred way of behaving around others. I suppose it puts to question more the existence of a _Space_ culture as mentioned by @called2voyage.

Comment: @RobertEnglish The problem isn't that there is a complete lack of culture, but that it isn't definitive enough to make this question non-opinion-based.

Comment: @called2voyage I'm not saying there isn't a problem. I'm saying the problem doesn't lie in the question being unrelated to Space Exploration. The phrasing isn't as rote as you would have it be. The problem is that the question is primarily opinion based because there may/may not be a proper answer out there.

Comment: @ZachSmith I don't think the question is off-topic, just that it is broad and opinion-based. It needs to be reformatted to be answerable, thus the close votes.

Comment: Even if we take "space etiquette" (literal or not) as on topic for this Q&A, this casts an awfully broad net soliciting a list of all behaviors one must observe in outer space. Seems a bit broad and unfocused. It's better to ask about specific situations about the day-to-day problems of "life in space." This is simply too broad a topic to be fishing for all possible issues on behavioral norms established in space.

Comment: There is _some_ evidence of this though. Just found [this](http://blogs.airspacemag.com/pettit/2012/06/an-astronauts-guide-to-space-etiquette/).

Comment: @RobertEnglish That post is specifically concerning dining etiquette on the ISS, a much narrower topic.

Comment: @called2voyage I think you may be nit-picking. It is still on topic. If I found that in 1 minute on Google, it's fair to say that other, more specific cases can also exist / be found.

Comment: @RobertEnglish One of the Community Managers for StackExchange agreed that your question was too broad and put your question on hold. If you want to discuss this more, please take it to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10716/discussion-between-called2voyage-and-robert-english).

Comment: FWIW I agree it's too broad too, even though I have been tempted to post an answer while it was still open, but simply didn't know where to start. A lot of this _space etiquette_ can be appreciated for example on Twitter, where I follow possibly all still active and many retired astronauts, so I saw some patterns forming. Also elsewhere. It is however terribly difficult to describe it in a few paragraphs, and still sufficiently answer the question this broad. I would've put it on hold too, but wanted the community to decide without a mod hammer. No hard feelings! ;)

Comment: @RobertEnglish, I see you were on line a couple of hours ago, and had not made any changes.  I took the liberty of trying to narrow the scope to your primary question.  I think it now is in scope, and have voted to re-open we will see if others agree.

Comment: @JamesJenkins IMO, that question is fine, but it is not Robert English's question. If he would take the time to edit his own question to make it better, I might reconsider. Otherwise, I would rather you post this so you can get the credit.

Comment: I'm ok with the edit. I like how it's turned into a psychological matter in order to cope with any cabin fever that one might experience whilst isolated in space for long durations.

Comment: @called2voyage, all I did is take off the extra stuff to narrow the scope, and add a couple of verifiable source requests.

Comment: @JamesJenkins feel free to undo edit and make another question I'm not pushed as long as the question gets an answer.

Comment: @RobertEnglish, I think it is still your question, it has 2 open votes now, and just needs 3 more. I am just helping your frame it better.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Since the OP approved, I voted reopen.